# Additional CSS for the nav menu

Tags: menus, css, navigation

I have customised the navigation menu on this site. Each main menu item has its own hover colour. My question is, how do I change the selected menu item colour to match in the sub menus. Currently I can change all to a different colour but what I want to achieve is a different colour for each sub menu selected item. It is currently set to a shade of orange.

www.clowntown.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the menu id for each menu item I could customise each menu heading as I needed.